# Q: HTML5 Canvas change background color

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am just wondering is it possible to change `Canvas` color from `function call`? I have this code with circle inside I would like to change outside color (background):

```
var canvads = document.getElementById('canvas')
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function circle() {
  var centerX = 0;
  var centerY = 0;
  var radius = 78;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);

  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
  context.fillRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);

  context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

  context.scale(1.5, 2);

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 5 * Math.PI, false);

  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.stroke();

  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';

  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  context.fill();

  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
}

function change_color() {
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,255,0,1)';
  context.fill();
}

circle()
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cs7ezuzf/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is to change approach a little - although it's possible to some extent to "fill background", the main way canvas works is constant redrawing of the whole image. In HTML games, it's done X times per second, but in smaller projects, it often should be done after each action. So, in your case, something like this should probably do the trick: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/44mesdg8/)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function initCanvas() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);

  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
  context.fillRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
}

function circle() {
  var centerX = 0;
  var centerY = 0;
  var radius = 78;

  context.save()
  context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

  context.scale(1.5, 2);

  // define the arc path
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 5 * Math.PI, false);

  // stroke it
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.stroke();

  // make alpha solid (the color doesn't matter)
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';

  // change composite mode and fill
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
  context.fill();
  context.restore()

  // reset composite mode to default
}

function changeColor() {
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,255,0,1)';
  context.fillRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);

  circle()
}

initCanvas()
circle()
document.querySelector('#but').addEventListener('click',changeColor)
```

And pay attention to save/restore, especially after transforms/rotating. Also, fixed onclick.

Comment: Please remember you've to redraw the circle every time when background color is changed. You can see the **circle()** function called inside **changeColor()** function in this answer.

Answer (score 10):

To set the canvas element background color you use

```
canvas.style.background = "red";  // a valid CSS colour.
```

You are filling the canvas with a transparent colour, if you want a colour that is the result of the element's background colour and the transparent fill you need to calculate the correct background colour that when combined gives you the colour you want.

To help this answer shows how to calculate blended colours. [Matching DOM colour blending](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39561132/3877726)

Answer (score 2):

The lines

```
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
context.fillRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
```

are setting your background color to black at 50% opacity (which about the same as #808080 or rgb(128,128,128))
Change this to have a different background color

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to have opacity.

Comment: You can still have that obviously, you can change the rgba(0,0,0,0.5) to anything else

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in your code.

```
<button on_click="change_color();">
```

should be

```
<button onClick="change_color();">
```

Please make this change and then try to change the background color as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score -1):

Simply do:

```
<style>#myCanvas { background-color: rgba(158, 167, 184, 0.2); }</style>
```

You can change it with javascript.
Check the same question here for more detailed responses: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488590/set-background-fill-stroke-and-opacity-of-html5-canvas)

Comment: Thanks, I tried but seems it does not work in my situation.https://jsfiddle.net/cs7ezuzf/2/